# Tesseract does not recognize Russian

Tags: c++, qt, tesseract

I am writing Qt app with tesseract-ocr library. 
When i tested tesseract, i found that it recognizes text only if it was initialized with 'eng' param. If i specify 'rus' param GetUTF8Text() returns something like this:
 `Ð¢Ð<9d>Ð<86>Ð<85> Ð<86>Ð<85> Ð¼Ð°Ð¼Ð°`

*.traineddata files are in /usr/local/share/tessdata directory. It also contains rus.traineddata file.

What is the problem?

Comment: Maybe your system doesn't support the Cyrillic alphabet?

Comment: I use debian wheezy, it supports the Cirillic alphabet) But during tesseract testing i had another problem http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/issues/detail?id=228. It was solved by setting locale setlocale (LC_NUMERIC, "C");. Maybe this statement causes the problem?

Comment: It is probably the cause of the problem. You need to do more Google search to discover how to setup your system properly. Your problem doesn't look like its related to Tesseract, Qt or C++.

Comment: I have installed debian-packages libtesseract3 and tesseract-ocr-rus. This console ocr-tool works fine with '-l rus' key. It recognized my test image without specially locale settings. So problem appears during calls tesseract api from c++ code, right?

Comment: Right, probably related to encoding strings when you receive the data from tessearct until the moment you decide to print them on the screen.

Comment: In Soviet Russia, Russia does not recognize Tesseract!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution! It is related to encoding text returned by GetUTF8Text function.

```
char* recognizedText = tessApi.GetUTF8Text(); // recognizes text with tesseract
QTextCodec* codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"); // creates UTF-8 codec
QString decodedText = codec->toUnicode(recognizedText); // Converts to UNICODE
```

It works!

Comment: And in case of using Visual Studio, not QT?